# DataNode and TaskTracker on separate machines?

Tags: hadoop

I am fairly new to Hadoop and I have following questions on Hadoop framework. Can anybody please guide on this?

1. Is DataNode and TaskTracker located physically on separate machines in a production environment?
2. When does Hadoop splits a file into blocks? Does this happen when you copy a file from local filesystem into HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given TrinitronX has already answered #1 - though the Short Answer should be NO - the datanode/task tracker MAY be on different physical machines, but it is uncommon. You are best to start off with "slave" machines being datanode plus task tracker.

So this is an answer to the second part of the question

```
2) When does Hadoop splits a file into blocks? Does this happen when you copy a file from local filesystem into HDFS?
```

Yes.  The file is broken into blocks upon loading into HDFS.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

1. **Most of the time, but not necessarily**.
2. **Yes**.

## Long Answer

### 1)

An installation of Hadoop on a cluster will have 2 main types of nodes:

- Master Nodes
- Data Nodes

Master Nodes typically run at least:

- CLDB
- Zookeeper
- JobTracker

Data Nodes typically run at least:

- TaskTracker

[The `DataNode` service can run on a different node than the `TaskTracker` service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10343397/645491).  However, the [Hadoop Docs](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/DataNode) for the `DataNode` service recommend to run `DataNode` and `TaskTracker` on the same nodes so that [MapReduce](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MapReduce) operations are performed close to the data.

For the [MapR](https://www.mapr.com/) distribution of Hadoop, the two server roles typically run:

- MapR Control Node

  - ZooKeeper *
  - CLDB *
  - JobTracker *
  - HBaseMaster
  - NFS Gateway
  - Webserver
- MapR Data Node

  - TaskTracker *
  - RegionServer (sometimes)
  - Zookeeper (sometimes)

### 2)

While most filesystems store data in blocks, [HDFS](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/hdfs/) distributes & replicates the blocks across `DataNodes`.  When you first store data in HDFS, it will break it into blocks and store it across different nodes according to the specified replication factor.  However, if you add new `DataNode`s to the cluster, it [will not automatically rebalance old blocks across them](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#If_I_add_new_DataNodes_to_the_cluster_will_HDFS_move_the_blocks_to_the_newly_added_nodes_in_order_to_balance_disk_space_utilization_between_the_nodes.3F) unless the replication factor is not met.

(Thanks to @javadba for clarifying this!)

Comment: Short Answer: should be NO. Tasktracker and datanode are on the same machine, not different ones. Your Long Answer is generally fine; however, one detail: there is no issue to run Zookeeper on either DataNodes or Master Nodes.

Comment: @javadba: Didn't see that `DataNode` was one word, so I suppose they meant `DataNode` as a service, not "Data Node".  I was told `TaskTracker` was the service that runs on data nodes, so in my mind I equated `TaskTracker` with "Data Node".  It seems that the [Hadoop Docs](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/DataNode) say that you should run `TaskTracker` and `DataNode` on the same server... am I mistaken?

Comment: Although it IS possible to have TaskTracker and DataNode be not one to one it is uncommon.

Comment: @javadba: Gotcha.  Edited my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Upvoting for your "Long Anawer" to #1).  HOpefully i'll get some attention for answering #2)

Comment: @javadba: Upvoted yours too ;-) Thanks for the assist!  I must've not noticed or remembered there was a second question until I saw you answered it too.  Just added some details on that too.  Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

1. Data-node and Job tracker can be run on different machines.
2. Hadoop always stores a files as a blocks during all operations on hadoop

Refer

1.[Hadoop Job tracker and task tracker](http://hadoop-gyan.blogspot.in/2012/11/hadoop-namenode-datanode-job-tracker.html)

2.[Hadoop block size and Replication](http://princetonits.com/technology/how-to-configure-replication-factor-and-block-size-for-hdfs/)